# Upgrade of DB slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've run the Magento upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7 a couple times on my Dev and Staging servers without many problems, but when I tried running it against the production DB, it's taking forever to complete (hours so far).

Is there a better way to upgrade the Magento DB?  I can't have the site down for hours to upgrade the DB.

Comment: I really wouldn't advise running upgrades whilst the site is live. You will likely trigger migrations to run multiple times, which take not only take much longe, but potentially cause other issues besides. This is aside from all the IO issues described by @Anton S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hitting the IO bottleneck here as magento uses innodb engine and between updates altering of large tables and dropping/creating primary keys takes forever dependant of your table sises and resources available.

In innodb when column is added the table is basically recreated and copied to temp table in progress so if you have 100k rows and poor IO on your database stack (not using SSD for example) then this is expected.

You can measure this easily by just doing a alter on your sales_flat_quote table or sales_flat_order (see which has more rows) and see how long it takes :) then multiply with all the alter commands you need to execute and you get your update time. Magento is somewhat stupid from this side and makes alters and key dropping/adding one by one not in one call so basically it is highly likely that you are wasting all your time on waiting alters to finish.

Comment: Thanks.  I took a look at the type of updates it's doing and since it's going from 1.5 to 1.7 it's doing a ton of incremental changes to the DB.